# convert hh:mm to float pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (first column is in `string` format):`

```
Time_string     Count 
23:10           2400
02:55           760
```

I want to add a third column which is the `float` of the first column:

```
Time_float
23.166667
2.916667
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty simple, as long as your timestamp only has the hour and minute components. Split, operate, and then combine -

```
y = df.Time_string.str.split(':')   
i, j = y.str[0], y.str[1]  

df['Time_float'] = i.astype(int) + (j.astype(float) / 60) 

df
  Time_string  Count  Time_float
0       23:10   2400   23.166667
1       02:55    760    2.916667
```